# scrape an api result page with scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I have this url that the content of its response, contains some JSON data.

```
https://www.tripadvisor.com/TypeAheadJson?action=API&types=geo%2Cnbrhd%2Chotel%2Ctheme_park&legacy_format=true&urlList=true&strictParent=true&query=sadaf%20dubai%20hotel&max=6&name_depth=3&interleaved=true&scoreThreshold=0.5&strictAnd=false&typeahead1_5=true&disableMaxGroupSize=true&geoBoostFix=true&neighborhood_geos=true&details=true&link_type=hotel%2Cvr%2Ceat%2Cattr&rescue=true&uiOrigin=trip_search_Hotels&source=trip_search_Hotels&startTime=1516800919604&searchSessionId=BA939B3D93510DABB510328CBF3353131516800881576ssid&nearPages=true
```

Everytime i paste this url in the browser with different queries, i get a nice JSON result. But in the scrapy or scrapy shell, i don't get any result. This is my scrapy spider class :

```
link = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/TypeAheadJson?action=API&types=geo%2Cnbrhd%2Chotel%2Ctheme_park&legacy_format=true&urlList=true&strictParent=true&query={}%20dubai%20hotel&max=6&name_depth=3&interleaved=true&scoreThreshold=0.5&strictAnd=false&typeahead1_5=true&disableMaxGroupSize=true&geoBoostFix=true&neighborhood_geos=true&details=true&link_type=hotel%2Cvr%2Ceat%2Cattr&rescue=true&uiOrigin=trip_search_Hotels&source=trip_search_Hotels&startTime=1516800919604&searchSessionId=BA939B3D93510DABB510328CBF3353131516800881576ssid&nearPages=true"

def start_requests(self):
    files = [f for f in listdir('results/') if isfile(join('results/', f))]
    for file in files:
        with open('results/' + file, 'r', encoding="utf8") as tour_info:
            tour = json.load(tour_info)
            for hotel in tour["hotels"]:
                yield scrapy.Request(self.link.format(hotel))
name = 'tripadvisor'
allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']

def parse(self, response):
    print(response.body)
```

For this code, in scrapy shell, i get this result:

```
b'{"normalized":{"query":""},"query":{},"results":[],"partial_content":false}'
```

In scrapy command line, by running the spider, i first got the `Forbidden by robots.txt` error for every url. I changed scrapy `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY` to `False` so it does not obey this file. Now i get `[]` for every request, but i should get a JSON object like this:

```
[  
{  
  "urls":[  
     {  
        "url_type":"hotel",
        "name":"Sadaf Hotel, Dubai, United Arab Emirates",
        "type":"HOTEL",
        "url":"\/Hotel_Review-g295424-d633008-Reviews-Sadaf_Hotel-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html"
     }
  ],
.
.
.
```

Comment: They maybe blocking you ip. Try changing  you IP address and User-Agent so it seems like its a new user

Comment: @tobey that does not help. i still get an empty response.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the sessionID from the URL and maybe check how "unfriendly" your [settings.py](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) is. (Also see [this blog](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/08/25/how-to-crawl-the-web-politely-with-scrapy/))

But it could be way easier to use [Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), like `wget 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/TypeAheadJson?action=API&types=geo%2Cnbrhd%2Chotel%2Ctheme_park&legacy_format=true&urlList=true&strictParent=true&query={}%20dubai%20hotel&max=6&name_depth=3&interleaved=true&scoreThreshold=0.5&strictAnd=false&typeahead1_5=true&disableMaxGroupSize=true&geoBoostFix=true&neighborhood_geos=true&details=true&link_type=hotel%2Cvr%2Ceat%2Cattr&rescue=true&uiOrigin=trip_search_Hotels&source=trip_search_Hotels&startTime=1516800919604&nearPages=true' -O results.json`